# CSS Methods to Style This Form

Tags: html, css

So I have a form like this, which currently has a bunch of text input boxes and a submit button. Rather than using a table (which seems like a messy method), I would like to use CSS. How would I format this in a way that looked presentable/professional (hopefully not too vague of a question?)

```
<h2>Add Record to Database</h2>
<form action="addrecord.psp" method="get">
Username: <input type="text" name="uname" size="12"/>
Machine Name:<input type="text" name="mname" size="8" />
Make: <input type=text" name="make" size="8" />
Model: <input type="text" name="model" size="8"/>
Service Tag: <input type="text" name="service" size="8"/>
Processor: <input type="text" name="processor" size="12"/><br />
Processor Speed: <input type="text" name="speed" size="4"/>
Amount of RAM: <input type="text" name="ram" size="3"/>
Type of RAM: <input type="text" name="ram2" size="4"/>
RAM Speed: <input type="text" name="rspeed" size="4"/><br />
Graphics Card: <input type="text" name=graphics" size="8"/>
Wired Mac Add: <input type="text" name="wired" size="17"/>
Wireless Mac Add: <input type="text" name="wireless" size="17"/><br />
OS: <input type="text" name="os" size="12"/>
Deploy Date: <input type="text" name="deploy" size="12"/>
Last Check-up: <input type="text" name="checkup" size="12"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<br />
```

Comment: This is extremely vague. What do you want it to look like? We have no way of knowing what your desired effect is.

Comment: Some Advice: Have a go at styling it. Read tutorials on CSS and how to work with specific HTML tags in your CSS markup. (http://www.w3schools.com/css/). If you run into specific problems, then come back and ask a question. I am sure people will help you then.

Comment: W3sSchools isn't a very good option. *[w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com/)* explains why and suggests other sources.

Comment: You should check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ -- you might get a friendlier response than you did here. (Seriously though folks, be nice to the new guy.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somes advices:

1. You should use `POST` instead `GET`, since `GET` is meant to retrieve information ([More info](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.3)).
2. You should also use the `<label>` tag in your forms, eg:

   ```
   <label for="uname">Username:</label>
   <input type="text" name="uname" size="12"/>
   ```
3. Try to align labels above fields. It make easier to read. [More tips on forms usability.](http://howto.caspio.com/tech-tips/tech-tipoptimize-your-web-form-for-maximum-usability.html)
4. Beyond that, you really should read some CSS tutorials. You may try [HTMLdog](http://www.htmldog.com) or [Dev.Opera](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/1-introduction-to-the-web-standards-cur/#toc)

Comment: I would also suggest setting a width on your <form> tag. Also set width's for your labels, and input boxes. You may also want to google CSS style forms

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if your data is represented as "tabular", then using a `<table>` isn't a bad idea.

Secondly, if you want to style this `<form>`, it's best practice to include `<label>` for your labels. How about this:

```
<h2>Add Record to Database</h2>
<form id="myform" action="addrecord.psp" method="get">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="uname">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="uname" size="12"/>
        <label for="mname">Machine Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="mname" size="8" />
        <label for="make">Make:</label>
        <input type="text" name="make" size="8" />
        <label for="model">Model:</label>
        <input type="text" name="model" size="8"/>
        <label for="service">Service Tag:</label>
        <input type="text" name="service" size="8"/>
        <label for="processor">Processor:</label>
        <input type="text" name="processor" size="12"/><br />
        <label for="speed">Processor Speed:</label>
        <input type="text" name="speed" size="4"/>
        <label for="ram">Amount of RAM:</label>
        <input type="text" name="ram" size="3"/>
        <label for="ram2">Type of RAM:</label>
        <input type="text" name="ram2" size="4"/>
        <label for="rspeed">RAM Speed:</label>
        <input type="text" name="rspeed" size="4"/><br />
        <label for="graphics">Graphics Card:</label>
        <input type="text" name="graphics" size="8"/>
        <label for="wired">Wired Mac Add:</label>
        <input type="text" name="wired" size="17"/>
        <label for="wireless">Wireless Mac Add:</label>
        <input type="text" name="wireless" size="17"/><br />
        <label for="os">OS:</label>
        <input type="text" name="os" size="12"/>
        <label for="deploy">Deploy Date:</label>
        <input type="text" name="deploy" size="12"/>
        <label for="checkup">Last Check-up:</label>
        <input type="text" name="checkup" size="12"/>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Basic CSS:

```
#myform {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    padding: 20px;
}
#myform label {
    display: block;
}
```

Also, I noticed that you were missing quite a few `"` around some of your element attributes. Be careful of that because it will break your code.

Answer (score 0):

Another good markup element for building a semantic list is the Definition List. Dan Cederholm writes about the technique here: http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Web-Design-Standards/Web-Forms/2/

This gives you a good structure to hook onto with your CSS when you style the form.

But to echo tcurvelo's answer and David Barker's comment you should really just start experimenting with the CSS once you have your structure established. I would suggest sitepoint to get a basic understanding of the different form elements at your disposal: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/elements-form

And there are plenty of tutorials available for achieving different looks for your form using CSS. The important thing is to start with a good structure that makes sense without CSS.